# Unit tests with Karma in Webstorm: Test results do now show

Tags: webstorm, karma-runner

Edit: This was solved in the comments.  I had an old version of Karma, and using the Project settings to update my version of Karma to the latest fixed everything.

I have a project in WebStorm and I'm trying to run the Karma unit tests I've written.  They've worked before, but all of a sudden (and I have no idea why), all I get when I try to run the tests is "Process finished with exit code 0" and no window showing the tests that should be run (or are running? I have no idea).

Here's my karma config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            '../../lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
            '../../lib/underscore-min.js',
            '../../lib/angular/angular.js',
            '../../lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '../../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            '../../lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            '../../lib/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js',
            '../../lib/angular-ui-date/src/date.js',
            'tests/helpers/**/*.js',
            'build/tickets-app.js',
            'tests/**/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'app/lib/angular/angular-loader.js',
            'app/lib/angular/*.min.js',
            'app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'
        ],

        // leave autowatch false to let webstorm do the automation
        autoWatch: false,

        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        reporters: ['spec'],


        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-chai',
            'karma-spec-reporter'
        ]
    });
};
```

In the Node.JS configuration, I have the node interpreter pointing to node.exe, the working directory set to the base folder of my project, and the .js file pointing to the karma.conf.js file.
Did I hide the test results window somehow, or is there something I messed up with the configuration that is causing the tests to not run?

Comment: Hmm... when running karma using Node.js run configuration, no test results window is shown - only plain console output in Run tool window. Why aren't you using karma run configuration to run your karma tests?

Comment: and, BTW, in Node.js run configuration you should be using a path to karma (C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\bin\karma, for example) as a javascript file. Configuration file name should be passed as an application parameter

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'd removed and then re-added the entire project from source control, and for some reason I had an outdated version of Karma that wasn't interfacing correctly.  and the run was using Node and not the Karma Test Runner to run my tests.  I went into the project configuration, got the latest version of Karma, and the Test runner appeared in the interface and everything started working correctly.